# Firebase token is not generating

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

im getting token is not generated..

the onTokenrefresh() is not calling. can anyone help.

it is connected to firebase also still the token is not generating.

```
public class MyFireBaseInstanceId extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveDeviceToken(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this. i just validated the token is null or not . If token is null then we will call ontokenrefresh() method.

The code is:

```
tokengenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (token!=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,token,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    RegisterToken registerToken = new RegisterToken();
                    registerToken.execute();
                }
                else
                    myFireBaseInstanceId.onTokenRefresh();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

are YOU sure that `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is properly defined in your AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
<service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Thanx for reply. i figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This** from any activity:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
String notificationToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

If still not getting token, There will be error on google-services.json file in your project

Answer (score 0):

1)Please check you added correct google-services.json file in your project. 
2)Check you added FCM services in your manifest file.

Comment: added but still same problem

Comment: check your google-service file is it correct or generate new one file with your  project  package. define in manifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

**onTokenRefresh** will only be called on certain conditions:

- App deletes Instance ID
- App is restored on a new device
- User uninstalls/reinstall the app
- User clears app data

So when you first launch the app it probably call this method but not when you launch the second time.

Since you use SharedPreference, you can use it to retrieve the token inside your activity.

Comment: i reinstalled but still same problem

Comment: <service
            android:name="com.example.bharathkumar.samplefb.MyFireBaseInstanceId">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.bharathkumar.samplefb.FireBaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Why did you update it here? Please update inside the post so that other people know where to look for the problems

Answer (score 0):

FCM generate token when you get Instance of FCM and refresh token first in the app.
when you need again You have to reinstall app in your device.

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the attribute of instance ID to the Android manifest file under the activity tab. Wrong addition of attributes in androidmanifest could lead to this error.